# Not able to build ios app due to Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRewardBasedVideoAd

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I have this error which i m not able to solved,
I set build active architecture = Yes
and other linked flags =  $(inherited)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_GADRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any way to solve this error

Comment: What 3rd-party libraries are you linking in your app?  (And how are you linking them?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.